# Convert SQL query to Lambda expression Linq ( GroupBy Having Min )

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I need help converting a SQL query to a lambda expression.

Query:

```
SELECT Sum(Total) AS SumOfTotal, CostSubGroup, Min(IsEstimated) AS MinOfIsEstimated,JobPricingCurrencyUnit
FROM tblCostBatchingSummary 
GROUP BY CostSubGroup, IsSubTotal, JobPricingCurrencyUnit
HAVING IsSubTotal = False
```

What I've been able to reproduce:

```
var ComputeCost= db.tblCostBatchingSummaries
.GroupBy(x => new { x.CostSubGroup, x.JobPricingCurrencyUnit, x.IsSubtotal })
.Where(m=>m.Key.IsSubtotal==false)
.Select(g => new { CostSubGroup = g.Key.CostSubGroup, CurrencyUnit = g.Key.JobPricingCurrencyUnit, Total = g.Sum(x => x.Total), MinEsitmated= g.Min(x=>x.IsEstimated) })
.ToList();
```

The error I currently get

```
The specified method 'Boolean Min[tblCostBatchingSummary,Boolean](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Earthwatch.Models.tblCostBatchingSummary], System.Func`2[Earthwatch.Models.tblCostBatchingSummary,System.Boolean])' on the type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because no overload matches the passed arguments.
```

Comment: I don't see why it can't translate, but you could put in `.AsEnumerable()` after the `.Where()` since you pull all the remaining groups from the server anyway.

Comment: For some reason, adding .AsEnumerable() made it work! Thanks!

Comment: I know you have you a workaround but it might be worth noting that the error looks to be from the translation of `g.Min(x=>x.IsEstimated)` to sql. What is the datatype of `IsEstimated` in sql?

Comment: IsEstimated is of type bool. I think I see what you're getting at.

Comment: yup. So g.Min(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.IsEstimated)) should do the trick!